# How to stop a cloudcontrol deployment?

Tags: deployment, cloudcontrol

My cloudcontrol app is stuck in deployment.

Both rollback and deploy give this message:
"Deployment foobar/default is currently deploying. Please retry in a few seconds."

Answer (score 1):

you get this message, when the cloudControl platform is currently deploying you application. In normal cases the takes at most some minutes, you can check the progress within the deploy log. https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Platform%20Documentation#logging